# Why does running mainloop() cause my whole computer to freeze?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a large, complicated program, one half of which involves a **GUI**, which I'm building using **Tkinter**.

Previous iterations of this GUI seemed to work as intended. However, in the latest version, when I try to run a demonstration (see the `demo()` function in the code below), **my whole computer freezes**, and my only option is to carry out a hard reset.

**Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be happening?** Some points which might be useful:

- If I run the code below with the line `self.gui.mainloop()` commented out, the desired window appears on the screen for long enough for the toaster message to be displayed, and then closes without any freezing.
- The ArrivalsManagerDaughter and DeparturesManagerDaughter objects transmit data wirelessly to another device, **but they shouldn't be doing anything**, other than being initialised, in the code which is causing the freezing. I don't believe that these are the cause of the problem, although I could well be wrong.

Here's the whole Python file which I'm trying to run. I'm happy to post more code if requested.

```py
"""
This code holds a class which manages transitions between the
"recommendations" and "custom placement" windows, and also oversees their
interactions with Erebus.
"""

# GUI imports.
from tkinter import *

# Non-standard imports.
import ptoaster

# Custom imports.
from erebus.arrivals_manager_daughter import ArrivalsManagerDaughter
from erebus.departures_manager_daughter import DeparturesManagerDaughter

# Local imports.
from charon.custom_placement_window import Custom_Placement_Window
from charon.recommendations_window import Recommendations_Window

# Local constants.
REFRESH_INTERVAL = 1000
# ^^^ in miliseconds ^^^

##############
# MAIN CLASS #
##############

class Comptroller:
    """ The class in question. """
    def __init__(self, welcome=False, delete_existing_ledger=False,
                 internal=False, diagnostics=False, path_to_icon=None):
        self.close_requested = False
        self.path_to_icon = path_to_icon
        self.recommendations = dict()
        self.arrivals_manager = ArrivalsManagerDaughter(self,
            diagnostics=diagnostics)
        self.departures_manager = DeparturesManagerDaughter(
            delete_existing=delete_existing_ledger, internal=internal,
            diagnostics=diagnostics)
        self.gui = Tk()
        self.top = Frame(self.gui)
        self.window = Recommendations_Window(self)
        self.is_on_recommendations_window = True
        self.arrange()
        if welcome:
            print_welcome()

    def add_recommendation(self, ticket, epc, column, row):
        """ Add a recommendation to the dictionary. """
        recommendation = dict()
        recommendation["ticket"] = ticket
        recommendation["epc"] = epc
        recommendation["column"] = column
        recommendation["row"] = row
        self.recommendations[ticket] = recommendation

    def remove_recommendation(self, ticket):
        """ Delete a recommendation from the dictionary. """
        del self.recommendations[ticket]

    def get_top(self):
        """ Return the top-level GUI object. """
        return self.top

    def arrange(self):
        """ Arrange the widgets. """
        self.window.get_top().pack()
        self.top.pack()

    def switch_to_custom_placement(self, ticket, epc):
        """ Switch window from "Recommendations" to "Custom Placement". """
        columns = self.arrivals_manager.columns
        rows = self.arrivals_manager.rows
        self.window.get_top().pack_forget()
        self.window = Custom_Placement_Window(self, ticket, epc, columns,
                                              rows)
        self.window.get_top().pack()
        self.is_on_recommendations_window = False

    def switch_to_recommendations(self):
        """ Switch window from "Custom Placement" to "Recommendations". """
        self.window.get_top().pack_forget()
        self.window = Recommendations_Window(self)
        self.window.get_top().pack()
        self.is_on_recommendations_window = True

    def refresh(self):
        """ Refresh the "recommendations" window, as necessary. """
        if (self.is_on_recommendations_window and
            self.arrivals_manager.clear_quanta()):
            self.window.refresh_rec_table()
        self.departures_manager.clear_backlog()
        if self.close_requested:
            self.kill_me()
        else:
            self.gui.after(REFRESH_INTERVAL, self.refresh)

    def simulate_recommendation(self, ticket, epc, column, row):
        """ Simulate receiving a transmission from the Pi. """
        self.add_recommendation(ticket, epc, column, row)
        self.window.refresh_rec_table()

    def request_close(self):
        self.close_requested = True

    def run_me(self):
        """ Run the "mainloop" method on the GUI object. """
        self.gui.after(REFRESH_INTERVAL, self.refresh)
        self.gui.title("Charon")
        if self.path_to_icon:
            self.gui.iconphoto(True, PhotoImage(file=self.path_to_icon))
        self.gui.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.request_close)
        self.gui.mainloop()

    def kill_me(self):
        """ Kill the mainloop process, and shut the window. """
        self.gui.destroy()

####################
# HELPER FUNCTIONS #
####################

def print_welcome():
    """ Print a welcome "toaster" message. """
    message = ("Notifications about boxes leaving the coldstore will be "+
               "posted here.")
    ptoaster.notify("Welcome to Charon", message,
                    display_duration_in_ms=REFRESH_INTERVAL)

def print_exit(epc):
    """ Print an exit "toaster" message. """
    message = "Box with EPC "+epc+" has left the coldstore."
    ptoaster.notify("Exit", message)

###########
# TESTING #
###########

def demo():
    """ Run a demonstration. """
    comptroller = Comptroller(welcome=True, delete_existing_ledger=True,
                              internal=True, diagnostics=True)
    comptroller.simulate_recommendation(1, "rumpelstiltskin", 0, 0)
    comptroller.simulate_recommendation(2, "beetlejuice", 0, 0)
    comptroller.run_me()

###################
# RUN AND WRAP UP #
###################

def run():
    demo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

---

FOUND THE PROBLEM: the culprit was actually **calling a `ptoaster` function from within a Tkinter GUI**. Which leads me on to my next question: Is it possible to combine `ptoaster` and Tkinter in an elegant fashion, and, if so, how?

Comment: Can you post *less* code to create a [mcve]? It is really not clear which parts are actually relevant, and we cannot run the code to try and find out.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I would, but that would involve having an idea as to which snippet of code was causing the problem! When the program crashes, it freezes without leaving me any traceback. I'm as lost as you are.

Comment: I understand, but please try and remove pieces and see whether that removes the problem. People will still attempt to help, but this gets much more efficient if you remove code (even if you do so later on).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Agreed. Working on that now.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Found the problem (see update above), but a full solution requires combining `ptoaster` with Tkinter, which I don't yet know how to do.

Comment: Feel free to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem ocurred when calling `print_welcome()`, which in turn calls one of the `ptoaster` functions. It seems that **Tkinter and `ptoaster` do not play together nicely.** Removing the reference to `print_welcome()` from the `Comptroller` class put a stop to any freezing.

(On a side note: I'd be very grateful to anyone who could suggest an elegant method of combing `ptoaster` with Tkinter.)

Answer (score -2):

Try changing

```py
def demo():
    """ Run a demonstration. """
    comptroller = Comptroller(welcome=True, delete_existing_ledger=True,
                              internal=True, diagnostics=True)
    comptroller.simulate_recommendation(1, "rumpelstiltskin", 0, 0)
    comptroller.simulate_recommendation(2, "beetlejuice", 0, 0)
    comptroller.run_me()

###################
# RUN AND WRAP UP #
###################

def run():
    demo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

To simply

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
""" Run a demonstration. """
    comptroller = Comptroller(welcome=True, delete_existing_ledger=True,
                              internal=True, diagnostics=True)
    comptroller.simulate_recommendation(1, "rumpelstiltskin", 0, 0)
    comptroller.simulate_recommendation(2, "beetlejuice", 0, 0)
    comptroller.run_me()
```

As to why this might happening, since you're creating an object by instantiating `Comptroller` inside a regular function `demo`, the object is not being "retained" after the `demo` exits.

**EDIT**

If you would like to still maintain `demo` and `run` you could create a `class Demo` and store the instance globally.

Or maybe a simple global variable inside `demo` to retain a "reference" to the instance `Comptroller`.

Comment: No, your code is intact, but you need to maintain a reference to what you create.

Comment: That's not how lifetimes work in Python. Until ``demo`` finishes, ``comptroller`` is *guaranteed* to live. Note that ``comptroller.run_me()`` blocks *and* references ``comptroller`` (via ``self``), keeping both ``demo`` *and* ``comptroller`` alive by itslef.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi My thoughts exactly. Even though it was a foregone conclusion, I ran Space's amendment, and it doesn't solve anything.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi On second thought, there do seem to be a few bits I could clip out of the code I've posted. I'll work on updating that now.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I forgot  Tk 's event loop blocks when `self.gui.mainloop()` is executed.